# How can I set a breakpoint in a function that I define on the Chrome JavaScript console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is this possible? I can't find such functions anywhere in the "Sources" tab. I suppose I could create a "Snippet" and set breakpoints in that.

Being able to set breakpoints for functions defined on the console would be more convenient though.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to hack it is to put the `debugger` keyword in your function.

```
function doit() {
  debugger;
  console.log('Here');
}
```

Comment: Right, I guess that would work. I typically copy and paste code changes from my IDE onto the console, so adding "debugger" statements is not really an option considering that. I think the best work-around is to paste into the corresponding source file in Chrome.

Comment: @GraemePyle mmm... Best workaround is to reload the code? That doesn't make sense, specially since there may be a lot of steps you'd have to retake to get to where you were in the app. You are answering your question by changing the premise of the question while I gave you a perfectly good way to do what the question actually asked.